# Decision of control mechanism (Necessity of if condition?)

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Suppose I have a profile page which has these values: name, last name, username, follower and following counts.

They may be updated after user logged into my application. So there is a refresh button. When user clicks to refresh button, I am calling a web service to get new values. In return, I get 5 values.

Here is example:

Suppose I have called web service and parsed return values into my `response` class.

```
// Here is first approach.

if (!response.name.equals(name)) {
 name = response.name;
}

if (!response.lastname.equals(lastname)) {
 lastname = response.lastname;
}


// Here is second.

name = response.name;
lastname = response.lastname;
```

In first approach, I believe `if` condition is required because if their values same, I won't lose time with assign operation. And also we know that `if` condition is the fastest operation can computer does.

In second approach, I believe `if` condition is not required because I already access both values in the `if` condition (`name` and `response.name`), instead of losing time with accessing them, not consider that they are same or not. Just make assignment.

Now, I want to know what is the faster way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you require if-else check when returning output from your web service call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is preferable ... unless you have made the mistake of using '==' to compare these strings elsewhere in the code<sup>1</sup>.

The flaw in your reasoning is here:

> *"In first approach, I believe if condition is required because if their values same, I won't lose time with assign operation."*

In fact, the assignment operator is likely to be faster than the `if` test, even ignoring the cost of making the `String.equals` call.  Assignment just copies a reference to a memory cell, and that is really cheap<sup>2</sup>.  It is NOT something you should think of "optimizing", unless you've got solid profiler evidence that it is a bottleneck.

---

<sup>1 - In that case, there could actually be a semantic difference between the two approaches.  But the chances are that *neither* approach is going to give you the *right* answer.</sup>

<sup>2 - In certain circumstances, an assignment to an object field could be a bit more expensive than a single memory write ... but even then, it is not something that you should try to optimize preemptively.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> More computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency (without
>   necessarily achieving it) than for any other single reason—including
>   blind stupidity. —William A. Wulf

That said, Java's String.equals() works by comparing lengths followed by comparing each character.

```
if (!response.name.equals(name)) {
 name = response.name;
}
```

involves a string comparison and a possible assignment.

```
name = response.name;
```

involves an assignment always.

Theoretically case 2 should be faster than 1. But there are many factors which can affect the relative performance of these two.

Comment: What if I have had 50 variables? It may be not considered for 5 variables. But what about 50? Would it make big time lose?

Comment: No. Assignment is a very cheap operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not proved this is a bottleneck, your time would be better spent elsewhere.

That being said, checking that one string equals another is probably more expensive than the assignment itself. That's my guess based on experience.

Which process is more efficient will also depend on how often the names are not equal to each other. If they are not equal to each other often, checking equality will certainly slow down your code.

I suggest creating benchmarks for this if you are truly concerned, but let me reiterate, I feel your concern is misplaced.

Premature optimization makes code less readable for naught, and wastes time.